# Just cleared my cache and cookies now I have the following errors

Tags: php, session, cookies

Thanks again for those who suggested and helped with my code.  Unfortunately, everything worked fine until I cleared my cache and cookies.  There were 3 error that were not there before.  The following errors are:

**Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Assignment_3\login.php on line 29
Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Assignment_3\login.php on line 34
Warning: session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Assignment_3\login.php on line 37**

The first 2 were a surprise because I swear I fixed that problem.  The last error on the other hand is brand new to me.  Haven't had that problem before.  I'll post my login.php for a better reference.  Again, any help will be greatly appreciated!

**login.php**

```
<?php



//GOT USER ID COOKIE? IF SO GET IT
if(isset($_COOKIE["userid"])) {
    $username = $_COOKIE["userid"];
}
//NO USER ID? GET THE COOKIE
else {

    //SET COOKIE, EXPIRE IN 600 SECONDS
    setcookie("userid", $username, time()+600 );

}

//SESSION ID IS OUR UNIQUE COOKIE
session_id($username);

//STARTING SESSION
session_start();

$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

//TOTAL AMOUNT OF TIME USER WAS LOGGED IN
$_SESSION['time_logged_in'] = time();


//THIS PAGE WILL PROMPT THE USER TO LOGIN WITH AN ALREADY REGISTERED USERNAME AND PASSWORD IN THE DATABASE
//IT WILL CHECK IN THE DATABASE TO SEE IF THE USERNAME AND PASSWORD ARE IN THE SAME ARRAY
//IF NOT THEN IT WILL SAY LOGIN FAILE.

//INCLUDE FUNCTIONS
include "functions.inc";

//IF THE ERRORS ARE SET TO FALSE, ECHO THE ERROR MESSAGES
if (!isset($errors)) $errors = array();

//INITIATE VARIABLE TO ACCESS THE USER DATABASE
$userfile = "user_data.dat";
$currentuser = "curren_user.dat";

//IF THE LOGIN BUTTON WAS PRESSED THEN VALIDATE THAT THE USER AND PASSWORD ARE IN THE SAME ARRAY
//IF NOT, THEN ECHO ERROR MESSAGE.
//IF THEY MATCH, THEN GO TO THE SUCCESSFUL LOGIN PAGE.
if (array_key_exists("login_btn", $_POST))
{
    $logins = arrayfile_to_array($userfile);
    $userlogin = $_POST['user'];



    if (validate_login(strtolower($userlogin['name']), $userlogin['pass'], $logins))
    {
        $errors['login'] = "Invalid Login";
        //break; taken out 11/9/2013
    }
    if (count($errors) == null)
    {
        //QUESTIONABLE VARIABLE
        $_SESSION['username'] = $userlogin['name'];
        header("Location: success_login.php");
    }
}


//IF THE USER HITS THE REGISTER NEW USER BUTTON,
//THEN TAKES THEM TO THE REGISTER NEW USER PAGE.
if (array_key_exists("register_btn", $_POST))
{
    header("Location: registration_page.php");
}

//PRINTING THE LOGIN USER INPUT FORMS.
//INCLUDES USERNAME AND PASSWORD.
//IF USERNAME AND PASSWORD DO NOT MATCH,
//HAS STUCKY FORM AND WILL ECHO ERROR MESSAGE AT TOP.
?>


<center>

<H1>Log In</H1>

<?php if (isset($errors['login'])) echo " <font color='red'>{$errors['login']}</font>"; ?>

<form method="POST" action="login.php"> 
    <table>
    <!--Text input for login-->
    <tr><td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type = 'TEXT'
           name = 'user[name]'
           value = '<?php  if(isset($_POST["user"])) {$tmp = $_POST["user"]; echo $tmp["name"]; } ?>'></td></tr>
    <br>
    <tr><td>Password:</td>
    <!--Password input for new password-->
    <td><input type = 'PASSWORD'
           name = 'user[pass]'
           value = '<?php  if(isset($_POST["user"])) {$tmp = $_POST["user"]; echo $tmp["pass"]; } ?>'></td></tr>
    <br>
    <tr></tr>
    <br>
    <!--Button to go back to form to fill again after errors are realized-->
    <tr><td><input type = 'SUBMIT'
         name = 'login_btn'
         value = 'Login'></td>
    <br>
    <!--Button to go back to form to fill again after errors are realized-->
    <td><input type = 'SUBMIT'
         name = 'register_btn'
         value = 'Register New User'></td></tr>    
    </table>
</form>

</center>
<?php 
//CLEARS THE ERRORS ARRAY
$errors = array(); 
?>
```

Comment: Where does username get set here setcookie("userid", $username, time()+600 )?

Comment: probably don't want to set the username if you haven't captured the user yet from the form?

Comment: Even if you get the username from the form are you sure you should set it before validation? What if they key it in wrong? It will be set in session incorrectly for the life of the session.

Answer (score 0):

in the line:

```
else {
//SET COOKIE, EXPIRE IN 600 SECONDS
setcookie("userid", $username, time()+600 );
```

you are trying to assign in userid a var that named `$username`.
but i do not see it anywhere.

if it is undefined so that where you problem is.